# why isn't the where condition passed to oracle in linq to sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, linq

Consider the following statements.  The first one is a LINQ statement, and the second one is old fashioned SQL.  They both produce the correct  result.  The LINQ statement takes 42 seconds because it doesn’t pass the where clause to Oracle.  Oracle has to do a complete table scan, then the where clause is satisfied by LINQ after the result.  In contrast, the SQL passes the where clause to Oracle, and takes about 3 seconds to run.

Why doesn’t LINQ pass the where clause to Oracle?  What can I  do about this?

LINQ:

```
var SamDlvryGrps3 = (from x in _entities.VW_QCRPT_SAMPLE_DLVRY_GRP_SITE
      where x.SAMPLEDELIVERYGROUP == EnteredsmplDlvryGrp
      select new BatchIdModView
{
     BatchId = x.BATCHID,
     sampleDeliveryGroup = x.SAMPLEDELIVERYGROUP
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

SQL:

```
string sql = "select distinct BatchId, sampleDeliveryGroup from VW_QCRPT_SAMPLE_DLVRY_GRP_SITE where SAMPLEDELIVERYGROUP = :1";
List<BatchIdModView> SamDlvryGrps = _entities.Database.SqlQuery<BatchIdModView>
    (sql, new OracleParameter("@smplDlvryGrp", EnteredsmplDlvryGrp.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

Comment: What linq provider are you using, and how is `_entities.VW_QCRPT_SAMPLE_DLVRY_GRP_SITE` defined?

Comment: Hi,

I really appreciate your reaching out to me on this.  The project I am working on is for the State of Maine department of environmental protection.  Any help you can be will be appreciated.

Here are the specific things you asked about:
1) The definition of _context:
   public partial class QCReportEntities : DbContext
    {
        public QCReportEntities()
            : base("name=QCReportEntities")
        { }
2) The version of System.linq, which is 4.3.0
3) Information about the Oracle view being queried.  In Oracle, it is a simple inner join of about 5 tables.

Comment: What data type does `VW_QCRPT_SAMPLE_DLVRY_GRP_SITE` return?

Comment: It returns two fields, both of them are character strings.  The where clause is also a character string.

Comment: Then you couldn't select from it. I must be something derived from `IEnumerable<T>` and/or `IQueryable<T>`. I was wondering if maybe it was only the former and not the latter.